# Checking if a number fits in a primitive type

Tags: java, beginner

I made a program that *asks for a specified amount of numbers* and checks if the input number is in the primitive type range. If it is, it "fits" on the primitive type.

Each input number, it checks if the number is in the range of each primitive type **MIN** and **MAX** range. If it is between the range, it prints the type(s) it is ranged on.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {

private Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

public Main()
{
    // Get input on how many numbers to ask for
    int t = in.nextInt();
    String input;
    for(int times = 0; times < t; times++) {
        // Ask for the number
        input = in.next();
        try {
            BigInteger number = new BigInteger(input);
            System.out.println(input + " can be fitted in:");
            if(number.longValue() < Byte.MAX_VALUE && number.longValue() > Byte.MIN_VALUE)
            {
                System.out.println("* byte");
            }
            if(number.longValue() < Short.MAX_VALUE && number.longValue() > Short.MIN_VALUE)
            {
                System.out.println("* short");
            }
            if(number.longValue() < Integer.MAX_VALUE && number.longValue() > Integer.MIN_VALUE)
            {
                System.out.println("* int");
            }
            // If the longValueExact() returns a greater number than the long max value, then it throws an ArithmeticException
            if(number.longValueExact() < Long.MAX_VALUE && number.longValue() > Long.MIN_VALUE) 
            {
                System.out.println("* long");
            } 
        } 
        catch(NumberFormatException | ArithmeticException e)
        {
            System.out.println(input + " * nothing");
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new Main();
}
}
```

I got this "challenge" from [this challenge website](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/java-datatypes). It may explain the challenge better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String input;
for(int times = 0; times < t; times++) {
    // Ask for the number
    input = in.next();
```

There's no need to declare `input` outside of the loop. It has no advantage at all as you don't need to keep it between iterations. Always minimize the scope.

---

```
       // If the longValueExact() returns a greater number than the long max value, then it throws an ArithmeticException
```

**As pointed in a comment, I misread `longValueExact` as `longValue`. Updated the answer, so that both are covered.**

For `longValue`, this isn't true and the Javadoc [says it pretty clearly](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#longValue()):

> if this BigInteger is too big to fit in a long, only the low-order 64 bits are returned

For `longValueExact`, the following is said

> If the value of this BigInteger is out of the range of the long type, then an ArithmeticException is thrown.

So checking for exception is correct. If it gets thrown, the number doesn't fit in `long` and obviously in no smaller type either.

---

```
        if(number.longValueExact() < Long.MAX_VALUE && number.longValue() > Long.MIN_VALUE) 
        {
            System.out.println("* long");
        }
```

By definition, there's no `long` bigger than the biggest `long`, is it?

So this test is a tautology.

---

Using `longValueExact` makes the program correct. With `longValue`, it wouldn't work and instead of testing if a number fits in a type, you test if its lowest 64 bits do.

Still, letting an exception be thrown for a normal program flow is extremely inefficient as the JIT assumes that exceptions are well... exceptional. Moreover, filling their stacktrace is pretty complicated and slow, as they actually don't exists in an optimized code.

In order to get a faster code, you need to do it the other way round: Convert to `BigInteger` and then compare. As a bonus to speed, you get compatibility with Java 7.

---

You should also fix your spacing and braces. Let your IDE do it, it's free.

Comment: the Javadoc you link is for Java7 but `BigInteger.longValueExact` was added in Java8

Comment: @No_signal I simply can't read... fixed it so that both versions are covered. Thanks a bunch!